# Javascript virtual web page creation

Tags: javascript, virtual, html

Within my javascript, I am getting BLOB and mimetype data from a SOAP web service.  This BLOB data represents a particular file's contents.  The file could be any mime type (image/png, text/html, text/plain, etc)

I would like to use the browser's (no particular vendor in mind) built-in ability to render the page based on mimetype.

Is there a way to dynamically generate a link or open a window that displays the file contents using the mimetype information?  I wish I could simply create an anchor tag that looks like this:

```
<a href=myBlob type=mimetype>open file</a>
```

Alternatively, something like:

```
myWin = window.open();
myWin.document.write(myBlob);
```

But I think this can only be used to write HTML in the DOM model :(

Any suggestions?

Comment: Set the `Content-Type` header or on the server .. or just use the extension and the browser will most likely use the appropriate program for display, if it has it

Comment: @ExplosionPills - I've got the file content assigned to a variable within my javascript.  Where would I set the Content-Type?  Can you give me an example?

Comment: This is something that needs to be done on the server side, not JavaScript (unless you are using a JavaScript server)

Comment: @ExplosionPills - The server is simply a SOAP interface into a database, so I need a solution on the client side

Comment: Got it...  use the 'data:' protocol as in:           window.open("data:"+mimeType+";base64,"+contents);

Answer (score 0):

```
window.open("data:"+mimeType+";base64,"+contents);
```